# How to change a serialized object?

Tags: c#, serialization

I have a lot of serialized objects saved as XML, but I would like to add 2 variables to these objects.

Here is my object:

```
public class MyObject{
    public Int32 MyVariables = 0;
}
```

This object has been serialized quite a bit, and I want keep the ability to read these "older" files into my application.

But I need to add a few more variables to make the object better, such as:

```
public class MyObject{
    public Int32 MyVariables = 0;
    public Dictionary<string,MyEnum> MyDict = new Dictionary<string,MyEnum>();
}
```

Can anyone suggest the best method to add these new variables? I actually changed MyObject and added the dictionary and I believe it is no longer being read in properly.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I'm also not able to catch an exception anywhere to see where it fails when reading in the object, I'm doing this to do so:

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter formatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
object obj = formatter.Deserialize(File.Open(Path, FileMode.Open));
```

Edit 2: I believe this actually may be due to me using an Enum as part of the dictionary, I added `[Serializable]` above the enum and it still doesn't work - thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the new variables.

If the XML serializer does not find an appropriate representation for the new variables, it will initialize them with default values.

Comment: I thought this would work (actually if I just make the type an int vs. dictionary it does, is a dictionary not serializable by default?)

Comment: You cannot serialize a Dictionary with XML Serializer.  There are, however, workarounds.  I'll try and dig up a link.

Comment: Here's one approach to using Dictionary with XML Serializer... http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/03/10/one-way-to-serialize-dictionaries/

Comment: Eric I'm a bit confused on to use this class now... I basically just created a variable of type DictionaryProxy, but I'm thinking I shouldn't be doing this?  As I later call .ToDictionary() and keep adding/accessing it, and it doesn't seem to be working as a normal dicationary

Comment: I think my issue is that I'm not JUST serializing a Dictionary object, but an object which contains the dictionary and other items

Comment: If the DictionaryProxy is confusing, have a look at this alternative approach.  It's more straightforward... just a drop-in replacement for Dictionary http://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/archive/2006/05/03/444961.aspx